# Slider goes backwards after reaching the last slide

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the slider reaches the last 3 images of the slider, it slides in backward direction to the first slide.

What i want to do is that when the slider reaches the last index then it goes directly to the 1st index in a row... It should not slides in opposite (reversed) direction.

```
  let slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides(slideIndex);

  function nextImg() {
    showSlides(slideIndex += 3);
  }

  function prevImg() {
    showSlides(slideIndex -= 3);
  }

  function showSlides(n) {

    let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("img");

    if (n >= slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 1;
    }
    if (n < 1) {
      slideIndex = slides.length - 2;
    }

    for (let slide of slides) {
        slide.style.transform = `translateX(-${100 * (slideIndex - 1)}%)`;
        slide.style.transition = "transform 1s ease-in-out";
      }
  }

  let intervalId = setInterval(nextImg, 3000);

  function revfunc() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    intervalId = setInterval(prevImg, 2000);
  };
```

Comment: When it reaches the last silde => if (n >= slides.length) { slideIndex = 1; } => slide.style.transform = translateX(- **0** %); so it goes back in reverse.

Comment: What i want to do is that I want the slider to directly go to the 1st slide instead of going (slide) in reverse direction

Comment: I'd recommend using a carousel plugin that has infinite looping functionality. What you need to do otherwise is duplicate the first image so it comes after the last one, transition to that then immediately move back to the beginning to make it seem like it's looping. There's a lot more to it than that which is why people generally use plugins for this.